# How to replace System.ComponentModel.Composition?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, migration

Good afternoon.

I am planning to move a large project from .net framework 4.6.1 to .net core 3.1. First, I decided to update/replace libraries that are not supported in .net core 3.1. For packet analysis I use .net portability analyzer (recommended by Microsoft).
The project uses System.ComponentModel.Composition to dynamically import .dll. Tried updating this package to the maximum version (6.0.0) - still not compatible. Then I tried using System.Composition and Microsoft..Composition - to no avail, although it says that .net standard 2 and .net 6 are supported. How can I replace this package for a successful migration to .net core 3.1.

Comment: Why are you migrating to .net core 3.1 when you should be migrating to .net 6 at this moment.

Comment: I replaced it by creating an extra project with .net standard 2 where my client interfaces & models were defined and implemented which needed this package but you should consider to use .net 6 instead of .net core 3.1.

Comment: @funatparties Okay, it makes sense to migrate to .net 6. But will that solve the problem with this package?

Comment: @Phael I correctly understood that you moved all the code that uses System.ComponentModel.Composition into a separate project? if so, will this project be normally built on linux or in a container?